Why do this universe needs to be destroyed at the end?
We all know that Parabrahma has created the universe as his desire. But, why does this universe need to get destroyed? Is there any reason mentioned for it?

Dissolution and not destruction. For those belonging to the Sanatana Culture, concept of LAYA is a dissolution process that is cyclic and ever in loop

The universe seen in sleep is - created, maintained and destroyed, when atma wakes up.
जागो लोगों मत सोओ, न करो नींद से प्यार ।
जैसा सपना रैन का तैसा यह संसार।।      - Sant Kabir

After waking up, there is another plane and anand+leela to be seen. These are eternal and never get destroyed.
Gita - यद गत्वा न निवर्तंते तद धामं परमं मम
This is very unique to Hinduism.
